# block specific type of email address in php via regex

Tags: regex, email-validation

I use the following regex pattern for validating the email address that works fine.

```
/^[^\@]+@.*\.[a-z]{2,6}$/i
```

But the problem is I want to generate error if email like `abc.abc@yahoo.com` are enter. Actually all those emails are invalid which have characters same as before & after `**.**` like `xyz.xyz@gmail.com` invalid, `qwe.qwe@hotmail.com` invalid

Comment: What's so special about those emails that you need to block them?

Comment: it looks like spam.

Comment: I think you want to use [`/^(?!([^@.]+)\.\1@)[^@]+@.*\.[a-z]{2,6}$/i`](https://regex101.com/r/X1LBoq/1)

Comment: thanks wiktor but barmar answer worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a back-reference in a regexp to test if two parts are the same. In PHP you'd write:

```
if (preg_match('/^(\w+)\.\1@.*/', $email)) {
    echo "That's a spammy name";
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That really helps alot